# How to Connect SVN server in C++?

Tags: c++, svn

I want to  connect an svn server and  download one file to my computer by using C++. How can I make this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Set up [WebDAV](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/http-and-webdav/webdav-usage.html) and use HTTP.
2. Use the [SVN client library](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/api/latest/index.html) and integrate using it.

I've done both approaches in the past. The SVN client library is actually quite easy to use.

### Edit

The subversion client library is described in [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html). Pay particular attention to [Chapter 3](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.html) and [Chapter 8](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.developer.html). I started by grabbing a source snapshot from [subversion.apache.org](http://subversion.apache.org/source-code.html) and reading the source code for the command line client. It's in `<root>/subversion/clients/cmdline`. I found that the source is easy enough to follow.

Comment: do  you know  any tutorial  concerned with  this  SVN Client Library?

Comment: @JohnFitzpatrick - sorry for not going back and updating the links since Apache took ownership of Subversion.  They are up to date now.